# How to disable modifying styles in word 2007?

Tags: microsoft-word-2007, styles

*I'm just getting used to styles (always did the formatting "manually") so this may be overly simple question to some.*

I wish to modify styles once and for all, and then give that "design" to some of my coleagues, and they will use it to write ... whatever they need to write. But I wish to restrict them from modifying it.

I.e. they should be able to make new documents using the given design, but shouldn't be able to modify the design.

*This make any sense? Any ideas?*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes makes perfect sense!

Simply get the document exactly how you like it, then expand the `Save As` option and choose `Word Template`.

[image]

Give this file out to people and they should have the default settings set to whatever you chose.

Comment: Wil - thanks for answering. Yes, I tried that now. But when I open the template file (with normal Open file) I can still change the styles. How to disable changing them ?

Comment: I don't think it is actually possible to disable changing them (without locking down the document / using an addin or macro), but by using a template it should always reset to what you set it to... you can even change the default.dotm one to make it always start this way.

Comment: not what I was hoping for, but one doesn't always gets all that he wants :) Anyway, thanks Wil !

Answer (score 0):

Wil is wrong. You can disable changing the styles. Use the Protect Document feature under the Review tab in the ribbon. You can even set a password so that no one can change the styles unless they know it.